# ggplot with x and y variables in different data.frames with a For-Loop

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, ggplot2, physics

I have two data.frames for my x and y value. This was done because each row represents multiple samples from the same individual, and each individual *also* has unique x-values. An example of my y value table:

| Group | subgroup | rank | diameter | ID | `peak 1` | `peak 2` | `peak 3` | `peak 4` | `peak 5` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Hym | Polistes | 6 | 4.3 | AD39 | 241.878 | 390.415 | 518.534 | 625.108 | 742.561 |
| Dip | Callip | 4 | 3.2 | AD42 | 45.937 | 102.299 | 151.484 | 182.305 | NA |

(but with ~200 rows and additional "peak" columns that go up to "peak 16")

and a sample of my x value table:

| ID | disp1 | disp2 | disp3 | disp4 | disp5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AD39 | 0.0591 | 0.118 | 0.177 | 0.236 | 0.295 |
| AD42 | 0.102 | 0.203 | 0.305 | 0.406 | 0.508 |

(again, the "disp" columns go up to "disp16)

So, here I have 2 specimens, basically undergoing stress-strain curves. "peak" is the force (g) from a given amount of displacement, my x-value, represented as a proportion of the total diameter being compressed (i.e., displacement/total diameter. Each displacement step is 0.254mm, so disp1 =0.254/total diameter, disp2=0.508/total diameter, etc.).

For my scatter plot, the y-values are the 'peak' columns, and my x-values are my 'disp' values.
This means the coordinates for the first point of AD39 would be (0.0591,241.878), the second would be (0.118,390.415), etc. As you can see from AD42, not all x-values have corresponding y-values.

I paired the data using a For-loop

```
dy<-read_excel(file name for y-value table)
dx<-read_excel(file name for y-value table)
n<- nrow(dx)

disp<- data.frame(NA, dim = c(n,16))
peak<- data.frame(NA, dim = c(n,16))
for (i in 1:n) {
  for (j in 1:16) {
    disp[i,j]<- dx[i,j+1]
    peak[i,j]<- dy[i,j+6] 
  }
}
names(disp)<- c(1:16)
names(peak)<- c(1:16)
```

then I plotted the data like this:

```
plot(as.numeric(disp[1,1:16]), as.numeric(peak[1,1:16]), pch = 20, xlab = "displacement", ylab = "peak")
#plot all points
for (i in 2:n) {
  points(as.numeric(disp[i,1:16]), as.numeric(peak[i,1:16]), pch = 20)
}
```

(I admit an acquaintance did the for-loop for me after I spent many hours trying to get cbind to work; I don't *really* understand for-loops very well)

Essentially, my end goal is to be able to easily separate the data into their various factor groups; ex. I want to compare my the 37 specimens with rank "6" to my 82 specimens with rank "4" by plotting them on the same set of axes, or my 45 "Hym" specimens to my 93 "Dip" specimens.

I think I could brute-force the code with a bunch of subset() functions, but there's so many factor groups that that would take hours and be the clunkiest code in the world.

I want to do this in ggplot, because it is the better graphing package and it also lets you subset data within the ggplot function.

Unfortunately, I cannot graph even a single specimen on ggplot, thanks to my For-Loop. This was my attempt:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=data.frame(x=(as.numeric(disp[1:16])),y=(as.numeric(peak[1:16]))),aes(x=(as.numeric(disp[1,1:16])), y=(as.numeric(peak[1,1:16]))))+geom_point(size=2,shape=23)
```

the error I get for this is "Error in data.frame(x = (as.numeric(disp[1:16])), y = (as.numeric(peak[1:16]))) :
'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'"

I assume this^ error is due to the "as.numeric" function in my data.frame. So I removed it, only to get:
"Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (167): x and y"

I assume the issue is the NA values in my y-values having "NA" in them. Not sure how to deal with that, to be honest.

So, after many twists and turns, here I am. I'm not sure if the solution is straight forward, or if it can only be solved by changing how I'm dealing with my data.

Comment: I would recommend reshaping your data to a longer format, where each sample gets a row, then joining the two tables, then adding a summary value for each individual with its rank. Feeding that into ggplot will then be very straightforward, eg. `reshaped_data %>% ggplot(aes(disp, peak, group = ID)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~rank)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's my suggestion:

First, reshape the two tables to long format:

```
library(tidyverse)
y_value_long <- y_value_table %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Group:ID), names_prefix = "peak.", 
               names_transform = list(name = as.integer), 
               values_to = "peak")

x_value_long <-  x_value_table %>% 
      pivot_longer(-ID, names_prefix = "disp", 
                   names_transform = list(name = as.integer), 
                   values_to = "disp")
```

Join them and plot, faceting by rank.

```
left_join(y_value_long, x_value_long, by = c("ID", "name")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(disp, peak, group = ID)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_path() +  # using _path here instead of _line b/c you might have multiple force values yielding the same displacement
  facet_wrap(~rank)
```

[image]

Comment: Having your data in a long format is always a good idea (in the world of ggplot)